# Directory Names in Batch

Tags: batch-file

How can I store a directory name in a variable inside batch file??

Comment: Where are you getting the directory name from?  Is it some constant you want to define?  An argument to the batch file?  The current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set dirname=c:/some/folder

echo %dirname%

REM retrieve the last letter of the folder 
REM and save it in another variable

set lastLetter=%dirname:~-1%

echo %lastLetter%
```

Comment: Whatever folder name you want to store!

Comment: The name of the directory that you want to store?

Comment: Tks... Another question that I have is that let say I have "dirname" now. Is there a way that I can get the last letter of this???

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of retrieving the last letter. HTH.

Comment: Substring is possible in batch: take a look for example at this reference http://www.ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html

Comment: @Valentin Jacquemin: That's exactly what my example does!

Answer (score 0):

To return the directory where the batch file is stored use
%~dp0

%0 is the full path of the batch file,

```
set src= %~dp0
echo %src%
```

I've used this one when I expect certain files relative to my batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Without more precisions it's difficult to help you...

Maybe you want the current directory?

```
set name=%CD%
echo %name%
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **set** command.

Example:

```
rem Assign the folder "C:\Folder1\Folder2" to the variable "MySavedFolder"
set MySavedFolder=C:\Folder1\Folder2

rem Run the program "MyProgram.exe" that is located in Folder2
 %MySavedFolder%\MyProgram.exe
rem Run the program "My Second Program.exe" that is located in Folder 2 (note spaces in filename)
"%MySavedFolder%\My Second Program.exe"
rem Quotes are required to stop the spaces from being command-line delimiters, but the command interpreter (cmd.exe) will still substitute the value of the variable.
```

To remove the variable, assign nothing to the name:

`set MySavedFolder=`

Since you are inside a batch file, I suggest surrounding your variable usage with **setlocal** and **endlocal** at the end of the file; this makes your environment variables local to the batch file and doesn't pollute the global environment namespace.

Answer (score 0):

To allow a script to determine its parent folder directory name:

```
@echo off
::setlocal enableextensions,enabledelayedexpansion
SET CDIR=%~p0
SET CDIR=%CDIR:\= %
FOR %%a IN (%CDIR%) DO (
  SET CNAME=%%a
)
echo %CDIR%
echo %CNAME%
pause
```

Or, better yet:

```
@echo off
::setlocal enableextensions,enabledelayedexpansion
SET CDIR=%~p0
SET CDIR=%CDIR:~1,-1%
SET CDIR=%CDIR:\=,%
SET CDIR=%CDIR: =_%
FOR %%a IN (%CDIR%) DO SET "CNAME=%%a"
echo %CDIR%
SET CNAME=%CNAME:_= %
echo %CNAME%
pause
```